# Android 1.6 SMS (older application code)

Tags: android, sms

I have [HTC Tattoo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTC_Tattoo) with Android 1.6. I have maed a Java program for SMS sending. I got the  source on the Internet, I think, versions before 1.6. The problem is: SMSs are sent twice.

What is a possible cause for this problem?

If possible, please simply post sample code what works OK.

Answer (score 4):

Cytown is 100% correct. I got a HTC Tattoo  with 1.6 and can confirm that it's working.

My code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            ArrayList<String> smstext = sms.divideMessage("asdfasdf");
            sms.sendMultipartTextMessage("5556", null, smstext, null, null);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

HTC Tattoo has a bug in `sendTextMessage`. Instead, you can use `sendMultipartTextMessage`.