# Android: Phone Sending 2 SMSs

Tags: android, sms

I used this code to send a text message

```
  try {
     SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
     sms.sendTextMessage(number, null, "Hi", null, null);
  }
  catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
      //show error
  }
```

For some reason the system is sending 2 messages. Does it have anything to do with the code?

Comment: Show also the code above this.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015259/android-1-6-sms-problem-older-app-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not your code. It's a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015259/android-1-6-sms-problem-older-app-code) in HTC Tatoo 1.6 (although there is also a workaround for it at the bottom of that thread).