# SmsManager sending message twice on device using Android 4.0

Tags: android, api, sms, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm using the package `android.telephony.SmsManager`to send an SMS message from within my application, and it seems to be sending the message twice on the test device (Samsung Galaxy S 2) running Android 4.0.3, but does not have the same issue on another Galaxy S 2 running Android 2.3.5.

I've debugged the code very thoroughly.

My question is, has anybody else experienced this problem on devices running Android 4.0.x, is there a work around? (I've tried this [Android 1.6 SMS (older application code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015259/android-1-6-sms-problem-older-app-code))

Also it would be interesting to know if the problem is only found on SGS2s or if there is a wider API bug (there is no mention of this package being changed in the API docs)

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with firmware (LPQ) specifically for Samsung Galaxy S2 running ICS 4.0.3 where SMS is sent twice on all 3rd party apps (including Handcent, GO SMS, etc) except stock messaging app. I think the latest version of firmware LP7 fixes the duplicate send SMS issue. Can you verify the base firmware version on your phone?

Handcent & GO SMS has found their own workarounds and upgraded their apks to market.

Comment: Yes the device is running LPQ firmware, sothat makes sense, good to know it's only an issue with one handset and one firmware version. Thanks for clarifying that for me, I wonder how handcent etc got around it?

Comment: [kestasb](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1312480/kestasb) [asks](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/234054) if you know what those workarounds are and how he can solve this problem himself?

Comment: Me too... Has no one found a solution yet?